# ISAPI_Rewrite to 301 redirect old domain to new domain, running ASP.NET4

Tags: .htaccess, asp.net-4.0, http-status-code-301, isapi-rewrite

I have two identical websites on different URLs:

http://www.oldsite.co.uk and http://www.newsite.co.uk.  I want to 301 redirect all requests from the old site to the new site for every kind of extension (e.g. 'index.htm', 'images/image.jpg', 'directory/subdirectory/' etc).  All references to any kind of file/document/path on the old domain need to be directed to the same place on the new domain.

The sites run a content management system which uses .NET4.

I've tried this two ways so far:  Firstly by setting up a permanent redirect in IIS.  This works to an extent but gives me a new URL like this:

http://www.newsite.co.ukeurl.axd/5e42bf571e13754bbed8710d 
2d377a5d/

All I've been able to find out with regards to the 'eurl.axd' stuff is that it's caused by the ASP.NET4 framework which is intercepting the request somehow during the redirect.  The only solutions I've found would involve disabling asp.net 4 (which isn't an option as the CMS runs on this) or doing some kind of registry hack, which I really don't want to do (bearing in mind there are other domains on this server).

The other option is using ISAPI_Rewrite.  I've tried this:

```
RewriteRule (.+) http://www.newsite.co.uk$1 [R=301,L]
```

But that too gives the same issue with the eurl.axd stuff.  So I tried this, which removes the eurl.axd stuff, but only seems to work for the homepage of the site - none of the other pages or resources:

```
RewriteRule (.*)eurl.axd/.* http://www.newsite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I run this there's nothing in the error log but the rewrite log shows that the rule isn't working as desired, e.g. trying to access 'http://www.oldsite.co.uk/technical.aspx' just loads that page in the browser (no redirect) and outputs this log:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /technical.aspx 
(1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf 
(1) Htaccess process request c:\inetpub\vhosts\oldsite.co.uk\httpdocs\.htaccess 
(3) applying pattern '(.*)eurl.axd/.*' to uri 'technical.aspx'
```

Does anyone know how to modify this rule such that it redirects all resources from old to new domain?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks folks.  The way I ended up resolving this was by deleting all files from the old domain and removing any dependencies on it to ASP.NET4 (changing application pool to one which doesn't use .NET4 etc) then just setting up the simple permanent redirect in IIS.  So I didn't end up using ISAPI_Rewrite at all - IIS handled it fine.

So now, anything at my old domain points to the new domain, which is perfect.

Thanks for your pointers folks, it's been interesting to look further into IIS, which I don't do very often.

Answer (score 1):

Create new empty web site in IIS, add .htaccess with your redirect rule to this web site and then point www.oldsite.co.uk to this site. So your .NET4 CMS will not be executed upon requests to old site and will not be able to change URLs before they get redirected.

Comment: That's an interesting alternative, thanks.  I need to be 100% sure though that my redirect solution redirects all resources though before I do this.  Does the standard IIS6 redirect do this?

Comment: Actually, going a step further, if I just disabled ASP.NET4 on the old site and set up the redirect through IIS would that work?

Comment: I can confirm that this solution doesn't work.  It works for the homepage but not any other file/folder/path.  If I create a new domain to do the forwarding on then I essentially have to create the entire folder structure too, but not using .NET4, which is not a solution.  It was worth a shot though, thanks.

Comment: This is only true with IIS6 built-in redirect. With ISAPI_Rewrite it will work. Just create new empty web site, point some test domain name to it and put your rule in the .htaccess in this site, i.e.:

RewriteRule (.+) http://www.newsite.co.uk$1 [R=301,L]

This way you could test a solution without changing your production domain name.